# Centering a div, margin: 0 auto; not working

Tags: html, css

After searching to center my div all I could get was margin: 0 auto; together with an assigned width, but still it not working.

My problem is simply centering a div. I have no idea why margin: 0 auto; isn't working.

Here is the layout of my CSS/html:

***CSS***

```css
    .countdown-box {
       position: absolute;
       width: 80px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       height: 130px;
       /*left: 50%;*/
       background: #008040;
       border-radius: 4px;
       z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="countdown-box"></div>
```

Comment: you want to center the div horizontally or horizontally and vertically both?

Comment: @Faizan Khan I want to center it Horizontally

Comment: You've absolutely positioned the element, meaning you've removed it from the document flow. Therefore, it will not respect margins the way relative or static elements would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using `position: absolute;`. Change it to `position: relative;` and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

The **margin: auto** works with elements with relative position. To center with absolute position should be like the following CSS:

```css
    .countdown-box {
        position: absolute;
        background: #008040;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 130px;
        width: 80px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="countdown-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually margin auto will allocate the available space, which means it doesn't has any relation with it is relative or not.

```
<div class="centerize"></div>


.centerize {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```